# Display a query from a SQL table in a text box

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've been tinkering with with this for over an hour now and am starting to feel poorly about myself.

I would like to capture a value from a SQL table, store it in a variable, and return it in a textbox.

Possible relevant information may be that I'm trying to make this happen on a combobox event selection.  Heres my code:

```
SqlCommand d = new SqlCommand("select @Name from OCRMonitor where OCRServer = @server", ProdrefConn);
d.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = platform.ToString();
d.Parameters.Add("@Server", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = server.ToString();

SqlDataReader reader = d.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();

txtName.Text = reader[0].ToString();
reader.Close();

ProdrefConn.Close();
```

I've had variations of this.  However, this is the first one not breaking the code.  But, its just returning the value of a column name.  Its executing off of this call on the combobox event change (server and platform are global):

```
ProdrefConn.Open();

if (cbServer.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    server = "Adtukfocr01";
    if (rbNuix.Checked == true)
    {
        platform = "nuixAssigned";
    }
    else if (rbLeverage.Checked == true)
    {
        platform = "leverageAssigned";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what output you are getting?

Comment: You can't pass column name as parameter.

Comment: Its a small table.  With three column headings of OCRServer, LeverageAssign, NuixAssign.  The return value is nuixAssign.

Comment: Put the name of the field that you want to retrieve instead of the @name

Comment: does the query work if you run it in the database? and i'm assuming you know the values of platform and server that are being returned, correct?

Comment: You could use a `CASE` statment, switching on the @Name parameter, to return the value of different columns, if you don't know at compile time which column the user wants

Comment: `SqlCommand d = new SqlCommand("select NuixAssign from OCRMonitor where OCRServer = @server", ProdrefConn);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is @Name a sql parameter, it should not be a SqlParameter, it is obvious that you are selecting a column value from table.

```
SqlCommand d = new SqlCommand("select @Name from OCRMonitor where OCRServer = @server", ProdrefConn);
d.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = platform.ToString();
d.Parameters.Add("@Server", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = server.ToString();
```

Changing this part of code to

```
SqlCommand d = new SqlCommand("select Name from OCRMonitor where OCRServer = @server", ProdrefConn);
d.Parameters.Add("Server", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = server.ToString();

SqlDataReader reader = d.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();

txtName.Text = reader.GetString(0);
reader.Close();

ProdrefConn.Close();
```

Comment: This solved it.  Thanks.  Stack over flow is fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

```
ProdrefConn.Open();

if (cbServer.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    server = "Adtukfocr01";
    if (rbNuix.Checked == true)
    {
        Query("nuixAssigned");
    }
    else if (rbLeverage.Checked == true)
    {
        Query("leverageAssigned");
    }
}




private void Query (string TableName)
    {
     SqlCommand d = new SqlCommand("select"+TableName+" from OCRMonitor where OCRServer = @server", ProdrefConn);

    d.Parameters.Add("@Server", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = server.ToString();

    SqlDataReader reader = d.ExecuteReader();
    using (reader)
    {
      while(reader.Read())
     {
      txtName.Text = reader[0].ToString();
     }
    }


    ProdrefConn.Close();
    }
    }
```